# jQuery ui multi select drag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need the below functionalities

1. select the items from list by mouse dragging and cntrl key similar to the jquery ui selectables.
2. Multiple items should be draggable at a time.

I need the application similar to the operating system drag and drop functionality.

my problem is if i would like to select multiple items the mouse pointer item is dragging, how to resolve it.

I was tried to use the code but it has some defects on selecting multiple items.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var selectedClass = 'ui-state-highlight',
        clickDelay = 600,     // click time (milliseconds)
        lastClick, diffClick; // timestamps

    $("#draggable li")
        // Script to deferentiate a click from a mousedown for drag event
        .bind('mousedown mouseup', function(e){
            if (e.type=="mousedown") {
                lastClick = e.timeStamp; // get mousedown time
            } else {
                diffClick = e.timeStamp - lastClick;
                if ( diffClick < clickDelay ) {
                    // add selected class to group draggable objects
                    $(this).toggleClass(selectedClass);
                }
            }
        })
        .draggable({
            revertDuration: 10, // grouped items animate separately, so leave this number low
            containment: '.demo',
            start: function(e, ui) {
                ui.helper.addClass(selectedClass);
            },
            stop: function(e, ui) {
                // reset group positions
                $('.' + selectedClass).css({ top:0, left:0 });
            },
            drag: function(e, ui) {
                // set selected group position to main dragged object
                // this works because the position is relative to the starting position
                $('.' + selectedClass).css({
                    top : ui.position.top,
                    left: ui.position.left
                });
            }
        });

    $("#droppable, #draggable")
        .sortable()
        .droppable({
            drop: function(e, ui) {
                $('.' + selectedClass)
                 .appendTo($(this))
                 .add(ui.draggable) // ui.draggable is appended by the script, so add it after
                 .removeClass(selectedClass)
                 .css({ top:0, left:0 });
            }
        });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo of multiselect drag

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zZTfA/11/)

Just use selectable plugin to select multiple items

```
$(".itemlist").selectable({filter:"li"});
```

Comment: The drag function in this example does not work in the 'drag and drop' context. The **drag** should facilitate moving the items, not selecting the items.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Selectable Grid example code and add Draggable + Sortable functionality as shown in this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but I need multiselect drag and drop

Comment: Update your question with your code and a demo fiddle, so that we can help you with your problem.

Comment: links were attached in the question